# Creating view with select query having sub queries

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SAMPLE_VIEW(MISSION_ID,"ESMP TRACK NO","RFPS TRACK NO","RADAR ID")
AS
SELECT ESMP.MISSION_ID,ESMP.TRACK_NO,RFPS.RFPS_TRK_NO,
       (SELECT RADAR_ID 
        FROM MATCHED_TT_DETAILS TT1 
        WHERE TT1.MISSION_ID = ESMP.MISSION_ID 
          AND TT1.TRACK_NO = ESMP.TRACK_NO)
FROM ESMP_DETAILS ESMP,
     RFPS_DETAILS RFPS 
WHERE ESMP.MISSION_ID = RFPS.MISSION_ID 
  AND ESMP.TRACK_NO = RFPS.ESMP_TRACK_NO;
```

I have created the above view and I'm getting an error.

ESMP_DETAILS table:

```
MISSION_ID    TRACK_NO 
A            4
B            5
C            6
```

RFPS_DETAILS TABLE:

```
MISSION_ID     RFPS_TRK_NO
 A             77
 B             88
```

MATCHED_TT_DETAILS TABLE:

```
MISSION_ID          RADAR_ID
 A                 5
 A                 6
 B                 4
```

I want output like below in view

```
MISSION_ID   TRACK_NO   RFPS_TRK_NO    RADAR_ID
A                4          77            5
A                4          77            6
B                5          88            4
```

Comment: CAPSLOCK is not your friend. Please stop shouting. And if you get an error, why on earth are you not posting the error message?

Comment: error is :   
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SAMPLE_VIEW("MISSION_ID","ESMP TRACK NO","RFPS TRACK NO","RADAR ID")
AS
SELECT mat.mission_id,
       esmp.track_no,
       (SELECT rfps.rfps_trk_no FROM rfps_details rfps WHERE rfps.mission_id = mat.mission_id),
       mat.radar_id
FROM matched_tt_details mat JOIN esmp_details esmp ON mat.mission_id = esmp.mission_id;
```

Comment: Why still use a subquery, instead of just joining the three tables? This would still error if there were multiple `rfps_details` rows for a `mission_id`; I'm not sure you can assume that will always be the case, from the tiny data sample.

Comment: In my view i have almost 30 columns in that i have to get data from 10 tables and some of the columns data i have get from lookup tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
CREATE OR replace VIEW sample_view 
AS 
  SELECT ESMP.mission_id, 
         ESMP.track_no, 
         RFPS.rfps_trk_no, 
         TT.radar_id 
  FROM   esmp_details ESMP, 
         rfps_details RFPS, 
         matched_tt_details TT 
  WHERE  ESMP.mission_id = RFPS.mission_id 
         AND RFPS.mission_id = TT.mission_id
```